# PHP How to find a line begining with a word from a text file

Tags: php

I have a text file with following lines

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   MIDlet-Vendor: Croco Gamez
>   MIDlet-Version: 1.0.0
>   MIDlet-1: Quan, /icon.png, CGTQ
>   MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.0
>   Created-By: 1.4.2 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
>   MIDlet-Icon: /icon.png
>   MIDlet-Name: Quan
>   MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0

I want to find the line start with `MIDlet-1` and Remove paragraph from end of this line
Please help me

Comment: What do you mean by 'remove paragraph'? Are you looking to remove the CR/LF line ending?

Comment: What should i call "down-line word" as? Please help

Comment: I've never heard it called "down-line word" but I expect you mean "carriage return" or "newline" :)

Comment: Oh i think it is LF, could you bedit my post, thanks :)

Comment: You can edit it yourself, I believe. The "edit" link is below the tags (and above these comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the `file()` function includes the trailing newline character for each line.  However this is only the default behaviour and we can instruct the function not to include them by using the special `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag.

```
file('thefile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)
```

To find the desired line, you could loop over each one and stop upon discovering the one that you want or use another function to search through the array.  Both of these have already been shown by [Krister](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8973995/113938) and [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8973962/113938) respectively.

```
$lines   = file('thefile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$matched = preg_grep('/^MIDlet-1/', $lines);
foreach ($matched as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Read the file into lines](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and then use
[PHP preg_grep ()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

With a regex pattern like this:

```
/^MIDlet-1.*$/
```

Then use [array_diff ()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get the array of lines which now
contains only the content you want. Write the lines back to the file if needed.

Example:

```
$lines = file ("file-to-read.txt");
$matchedLines = preg_grep ('/^MIDlet-1.*$/', $lines);
$lines = array_diff ($lines, $matchedLines);

// do something with lines which doesn't have your MIDlet data
```

Comment: I want to echo MIDlet-1: Quan, /icon.png, CGTQ with no down-line word at the end, please help

Comment: That is the full code... Everything except for what you need to do with your data in the end game.